# Save many files db.files from list names into file

Tags: shell, bind

I need help with my shell script. I tried to run it, but it doesn't work.

My logic is create many db.files to BIND service. I have one file with many lines that will be zones. I would like to save many files in folder.

```
 #./script.sh file


 ###################
 #script.sh
 ###################


 #!/bin/bash
 while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
     echo '$TTL    86400'
     echo $line'.exemplo.com.br.        IN      SOA     ns1.exemplo.com.br.     hostmaster.exemplo.com.br.('
     echo '        2016020601      ; serial'
     echo '        3600            ; refresh (1h)'
     echo '        1800            ; retry (30m)'
     echo '        86400           ; expire (1d)'
     echo '        900 )           ; minimum (15m)'<

     echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns1.exemplo.com.br.'
     echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns2.exemplo.com.br.'
     echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns3.exemplo.com.br.'
     echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns4.exemplo.com.br.'
     echo "\n\n"
 done >"$1"
```

This script prints to the terminal, but I want to save to many files.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 let $count = $count + 1
 echo '$TTL    86400' > file_out_$count.extension
 echo $line'.exemplo.com.br.        IN      SOA     ns1.exemplo.com.br.     hostmaster.exemplo.com.br.(' >> file_out_$count.extension
 echo '        2016020601      ; serial' >> file_out_$count.extension
 echo '        3600            ; refresh (1h)' >> file_out_$count.extension
 echo '        1800            ; retry (30m)' >> file_out_$count.extension
 echo '        86400           ; expire (1d)' >> file_out_$count.extension
 echo '        900 )           ; minimum (15m)' >> file_out_$count.extension

 echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns1.exemplo.com.br.'>> file_out_$count.extension

 echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns2.exemplo.com.br.'>> file_out_$count.extension

 echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns3.exemplo.com.br.'>> file_out_$count.extension

 echo ';'$line'.exemplo.com.br.             IN NS ns4.exemplo.com.br.'>> file_out_$count.extension

 echo "\n\n" >> file_out_$count.extension
```

This is a dirty solution considering that every loop will generate a different file.